# Multiply measure by column without aggregating the latter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the below dataset and user country as a filter. The task is to calculate the revenue - calculated as cum sum paid in this month - cum sum paid in the previous month. It should be calculated in USD. The solution of multiplying the exchange rate in the below table, then, creating a measure using PREVIOUSMONTH and then, doing subtraction doesn't work because of the high exchange rate fluctuation.

[image]

The solution we came with was to calculate the revenue in the local currency. And then, if a user selects Switzerland from the filter, the revenue will be multiplied by the exchange rate for the corresponding country and corresponding date.

[image]

Here are the formulas in practice. My issue is that I cannot find a way to multiply by the actual exchange rate as I need to aggregate exchange rate somehow and I am currently multiplying by averagex.

Measures:

```
prior_month_sum_lc = CALCULATE(sum(fact_payment[sum_paid_to_date]),PREVIOUSMONTH(calendar_3[Date]))
 
revenue = sum(fact_payment[sum_paid_to_date])-[prior_month_sum_lc] 
 
revenue_used = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(fact_payment[country])="Spain",
[revenue] * AVERAGEX(fact_payment,fact_payment[xr_es]),0 )
```

Calculation done manually
[image]

Comment: Actually, it got resolved. The question is how to aggregate when no selection is made.

Comment: What got resolved? Do you still have a question? If so, state what it is, because it is not clear. Please include an example of the desired results

Comment: @MarcoVos, the formula above works just fine for the individual country selection but not when Select all is selected. Shall I open another thread? I've published the sample at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADLoDNSVBFo-G_SYj30xPH490yTDNXrL/view?usp=sharing where final_selection contains the formula I was working on. What does not work is Previousmonth when no country is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you set this up correctly. You should not average the Exchange-rates. That makes no sense. In stead you should multiply each amount with its exchange-rate on the rowlevel and sum the results. For this you should use the SUMX-function. Furthermore it's not necessary to split the exchange-rates into two columns. Just use one column. These are my results:

[image]

Here are the measures I used:

```
Month_Sum = sum(Sheet1[cum sum paid])
Month_Sum_Exchanged = SUMX('Sheet1','Sheet1'[cum sum paid] * 'Sheet1'[xr])
Previous_Month_Sum = CALCULATE([Month_Sum],PREVIOUSMONTH(calendar_3[Date]))
Previous_Month_Sum_Exchanged = CALCULATE([Month_Sum_Exchanged],PREVIOUSMONTH(calendar_3[Date]))
Revenue = [Month_Sum] - [Previous_Month_Sum]
Revenue_Exchanged = [Month_Sum_Exchanged] - [Previous_Month_Sum_Exchanged]
```

This is a link to my [pbix file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ju5vg50hcvsz0z/SO%207-15-2019.pbix?dl=0)

Comment: nope, it gives an incorrect result - I did the calculation manually in xls and the results match what I have - see I've updated the response.

Comment: Please be more specific. What result is incorrect? Did you notice that your result is filtered to Spain and mine is not?

Comment: Sure, as you can see from the screenshot, my result from the manual calculation in xls and in Power BI is 2.26; 5.75; 3.9 and in urs, it is 2.26; 5.89; 5.7. The reason I am saying it is incorrect because I confirmed it with doing the calc in xls manually.

Comment: I think you you are still using averaged exchange-rates, which would explain the difference between our results. This is incorrect or at least  not accurate. If you did not: how did you manualy calculate your values then?

Comment: No, in xls I am not averaging it - see the screenshot. I've uploaded the calculation at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xnZUBnLSyaAXg3K9hKQ3Nk4KkkeZ7We_/view?usp=sharing. I guess we could come to the agreement that miracly, avergex worked out.

Comment: This is the difference: when calculating [sum paid] for the previous month, you should also use the exchangerate from the previous month. So the correct calculation for the revenue in March is (12*1.15) - (7*1.13) = 5.89. Your calculation is : (12-7) * 1.15 = 5.75, which is not correct (i think;-)

Comment: The reason that AVERAGEX works here is because the exchangerate does not change during a month. As soon as it does, or if you want do do a calculation for a longer period, AVERAGEX will no longer give the correct results.

Comment: Thank you, Marco, and any suggestions on how to handle Select All? For me the previousmonth is not calculated.

Comment: Your welcome. The Select all does work in my set up, so check out my pbix-file.

Comment: I still have my doubts about your calculation. The reason I am calculating like that is that we discussed this type of calculation with the stakeholder. And you could agree that in April we got quite a substantial difference. I did something similar to what you did but on the account level i.e. cum sum * exchange rate. Then, summed it up, then, took the previous month cum sum * exchange rate and did the subtraction to get the revenue and the results were almost 2 times less than the company actually received. Ah, and this particular dataset is updated monthly, so no daily fluctuation.

Comment: At least we know now where the difference in results came from. It's up to you and the stakeholders to agree on how the revenue should be calculated. No wrong or right way i guess.... All the best!